# Proof that for $G=(GL_2(F), $ matrix multiplication$)$, $H$ is not a subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

I'm working on a proof aimed at showing that for non-abelian groups, $H=${$x\in G| x^2=e$} is not a subgroup. I chose as a counterexample $G=(GL_2(F), $matrix multiplication$)$, to show $H=${$x\in G| x^2=e$} is not a subgroup.

My notation is: $GL_2(F)$: The set of all invertible $2$ by $2$ matrices consisting of elements from some field, $F$. $e$ is the identity element of $G$.

Side note: I am a novice when it comes to group theory.

First, let $A$, $B\in H$. If we assume closure for contradiction, then $AB$, $BA\in H$.

My question: Can I choose that $AB\neq BA$ since I am choosing them from a non-abelian group?

If so, my proof continues as $(AB)^{2}=e \implies (AB)=(AB)^{-1}$

Yet, we have $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}=BA$ and hence $AB=BA$, a contradiction to our earlier choice.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You picked a specific example but then retreated to non-specific arguments. That will never work. Your example is also too complicated. I recommend trying to prove it for the symmetric group $S_3$. The set $\{x\in S_3|x^2=e\}$ has $4$ elements, and $S_3$ has $6$ elements. Do you see the problem?

Comment: Thank you! While I see your point concerning the symmetric group $S_3$,  I found your comment concerning "retreat[ing] to non-specific arguments" even more fruitful.

Comment: @EthanZell You're welcome.